# Unable to get Intent from SMSReceiver

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I'm writing an app which send some geopoints with sms and receive it, showing it on map.
it gets the sms in SMSReceiver and put part of sms in bundle and call the MapActivity.
the problem is that the MapActivity doesn't show any geopoints.
I get the toast in SMSReceiver..so i don't think there is any problem with that and the MapActivity runs but i don't get any marker...Does anyone have an idea where the problem is???

Here is my SMSReceiver:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";;
private static final String GEOPINTS = "geoPoints";
Long user_id;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        android.telephony.SmsMessage[] msg = null;
        long sender = -1;
        String geoPoints = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msg = new android.telephony.SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (msg[i].getMessageBody().startsWith(GEOPINTS)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "geoPoints received.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // abortBroadcast();
                    String number = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    number = number.substring(3);
                    sender = Long.parseLong(number);
                    geoPoints = msg[i].getMessageBody();
                    geoPoints = geoPoints.substring(9);
                    Intent mapActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MapActivity.class);
                    mapActivityIntent.putExtra("GEOPOINTS", geoPoints);
                    mapActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(mapActivityIntent);
                } 
            }
        }

    }
}}
```

and here is my MapActivity:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private static final long ONE_MIN = 1000 * 60;
private static final long TWO_MIN = ONE_MIN * 2;
private static final long FIVE_MIN = ONE_MIN * 5;
private static final long MEASURE_TIME = 1000 * 30;
private static final long POLLING_FREQ = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTES_UPDATE_FREQ = 1000 * 2;
private static final float MIN_ACCURACY = 25.0f;
private static final float MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY = 500.0f;

private Location mBestReading;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;

private final String TAG = "MapActivity";
private GoogleMap googleMap;
Long user_id;
String user_name;
String friend_name;
ImageView imageView;
private static String USER_ID = "USER_ID";
ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person>();
ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    user_id = Long.valueOf(prefs.getLong(USER_ID, 0L));
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tinyImage);
    TextView userNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tinyUserName);
    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
    User user = new User();
    user = db.getUserId(user_id);
    user_name = user.getName();
    userNameText.setText(user_name);
    byte[] image = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    image = user.getImage();
    if (image != null) {
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_default);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tinyImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("GEOPOINTS")) {
        String geoPoints = bundle.getString("GEOPOINTS");
        if (geoPoints != null) {
            String latlng = "";
            Double lat = null;
            Double lng = null;
            LatLng point = null;
            do {
                latlng = geoPoints.substring(0, geoPoints.indexOf("\n"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latlng.substring(0, latlng.indexOf(" ")));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(latlng.substring(latlng.indexOf(" ") + 1));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lat = " + lat + " lng = " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                point = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(point);
                if (geoPoints.indexOf("\n") != geoPoints.indexOf(geoPoints.length())) {
                    geoPoints = geoPoints.substring(geoPoints.indexOf("\n") + 1);
                } else {
                    geoPoints = "";
                }
            } while (!geoPoints.equals(""));

        }
    }
    // Check if google play service , GPS & network is enabled
    if (!servicesAvailable())
        finish();

    // Create new Location Client. This class will handle call backs
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    // Create and define the LocationRequest
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Update every 10 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(POLLING_FREQ);

    // Receive updates no more often than every 2 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTES_UPDATE_FREQ);

}

private void addDirectionMarker() {
    if (points != null) {
        for (LatLng point : points) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).icon(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        }
    }

}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker mark) {
            if (!mark.getTitle().equals("You are here!") && !mark.getTitle().equals(null)) {
                friend_name = mark.getTitle();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChoiceActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("FRIEND_NAME", friend_name);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Connect to LocationServices
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    // Stop updates
    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

    // Disconnect from LocationServices
    mLocationClient.disconnect();

    super.onStop();
}

// Get the last known location from all providers
// return best reading that is as accurate as minAccuracy and
// was taken no longer then minAge milliseconds ago. If none,
// return null.

private Location bestLastKnownLocation(float minAccuracy, long maxAge) {

    Location bestResult = null;
    float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    long bestTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    // Get the best most recent location currently available
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

    if (mCurrentLocation != null) {

        float accuracy = mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy();
        long time = mCurrentLocation.getTime();

        if (accuracy < bestAccuracy) {

            bestResult = mCurrentLocation;
            bestAccuracy = accuracy;
            bestTime = time;

        }
    }

    // Return best reading or null
    if (bestAccuracy > minAccuracy || (System.currentTimeMillis() - bestTime) > maxAge) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return bestResult;
    }
}

private boolean servicesAvailable() {

    // Check that Google Play Services are available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available

    return (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
    addFriendsMarker();
    addDirectionMarker();
}

public void setUserLocation(Location location) {

    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(user_id);
    com.bhproj.test.gpstrackertest.model.Location loc = new com.bhproj.test.gpstrackertest.model.Location(
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    user.setLocation(loc);
    db.updateLocUser(user);
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("You are here!")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    googleMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).build()), 2000, null);

}

public void addFriendsMarker() {
    DataBaseAdapter db = new DataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    List<Person> persons = db.getFriends(user_id);
    if (persons != null) {
        for (Person friend : persons) {
            friends.add(friend);
        }
        if (friends != null) {
            for (Person i : friends) {
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(i.getLocation().getLatitude(), i.getLocation().getLongitude()))
                        .title(i.getName())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void goToUserPageOnClickListener(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserPageActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Determine whether new location is better than current best
    // estimate

    if (null == mBestReading || location.getAccuracy() < mBestReading.getAccuracy()) {

        // Update best estimate
        mBestReading = location;

        // Update display
        googleMap.clear();
        setUserLocation(location);
        addFriendsMarker();

        if (mBestReading.getAccuracy() < MIN_ACCURACY)
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed. Try again later.");

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // Get first reading. Get additional location updates if necessary

    if (servicesAvailable()) {
        // Get best last location measurement meeting criteria
        mBestReading = bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);

        // Display last reading information
        if (null != mBestReading) {

            googleMap.clear();
            setUserLocation(mBestReading);
            addFriendsMarker();

            // } else {
            //
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "No Initial Reading Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        if (null == mBestReading || mBestReading.getAccuracy() > MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY
                || mBestReading.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - TWO_MIN) {

            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);

            // Schedule a runnable to unregister location listeners
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(MapActivity.this);

                }
            }, MEASURE_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected. Try again later.");

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your broadcasereceiver do something like this:  (use that intent)

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String NOTIFICATION = "receiver_sms";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("onReceive methode", "new SMS Comming");

    Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] messages = null;
    String strMessage = "", address = "";
    abortBroadcast();
    if (myBundle != null) {
        // get message in pdus format(protocol description unit)
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
        // create an array of messages
        messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        Log.i("onReceive methode", "new SMS Comming");
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            // Create an SmsMessage from a raw PDU.
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // get the originating address (sender) of this SMS message in
            // String form or null if unavailable
            address = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            // get the message body as a String, if it exists and is text
            // based.
            strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
            strMessage += "\n";
        }

        // show message in a Toast
    }
        // this is what you need
        Intent broadcast = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        broadcast.putExtra("data", strMessage);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(broadcast);

}
```

and then register ur receiver in ur activity

```
public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(tag, "SMS Received.");            
        Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("SMS");
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        parseSMSData(str);
    }
};
```

and then in onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(SMSReceiver.NOTIFICATION));
}
```

and in onDestroy() you must unregister that receiver like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and also don't forget to add this in ur manifest file in application tag:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

Instead if `Intent i = new Intent();` for getting Intent which you are passing in `startActivity` from  `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: thanks...I didn't notice that..but still no  difference.